# Ionic: How to get the Apple ID

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, app-store-connect

I am using Ionic3 and would like to know if it's possible to determine what the devices Apple Id is?

According to Apple:

> Non-renewable subscription content must be made available to all iOS
>   devices owned by a single user, as indicated in guideline 3.1.2 of the
>   App Store Review Guidelines.

So I need to save the subscription to the users Apple Id.

**Question**

With Ionic, how do you obtain a users Apple ID?

Comment: Can you please ask the question in another way exactly what do you want. Because looks like you are confused with this process

Comment: Hi Sivajee, I have added a Question above. Is that clearer?

Comment: You can't get the Apple ID. How do you want to use it? So that I can tell exactly what to do

Comment: I have an app that allows a user to make in-app purchases. A purchase allows a user to subscribe to extra functionality for a given period of time. I developed it to use `consumable` iaps, and each time the user makes a purchase, say for 3 days, I add 3 days to their current subscription. However, in review, Apple has said that I should rather use `non-renewable subscription` iaps, and I need to comply with the above `guideline 3.1.2`. Any advise on my best way to handle this?

Comment: If you've already implemented IAP in your app, then you should be familiar with the various StoreKit APIs.  Your app doesn't specifically acquire the users AppleID, but instead uses StoreKit to access subscription information.

Comment: I do make the users login to Firebase Auth via Facebook, Google or Email before they can make a purchase, so planned to associate their subscription with their Firebase account. That was the plan, until Apple said that it needs to be available on all devices owned by the user. (I planned to have it on all devices where the user is signed in).

Comment: When user login with the same apple ID from which he/she bought in-app purchase, the same product will be available for the user on all devices. You don't need to do anything for this.

Comment: All you need to do is create an non-renewable identifier from itunes and make it approved then use that product identifier. If you don't understand what's non-renwable products and all. Here is a glance of it https://www.codenameone.com/blog/in-app-purchase-non-renewable-subscriptions.html

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look.